# Call functions from another account by default in web3

Tags: web3js, truffle-test

In my truffle tests, I am trying to call a function from an account other than the default account, so not `accounts[0]` from the below result. `web3.eth.defaultAccount` doesn't seem to work.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
  accounts[0] // Don't use this.
  web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[1].
  contractInstance.foo() // called from accounts[0]
})
```

I know I can use

```
contractinstance.foo({from: accounts[1]})
```

but I don't want to add this parameter every time, as most of the code will use `accounts[1]`.

Is there a way to change the default account or am I missing something here? Thanks

Comment: I'm personally not aware of any other way. if you find it troubling to write `contractinstance.foo({from: accounts[1]})` in many places, then put it inside a function and call that function instead (declare and implement that function inside the function which takes `accounts` as an input parameter, so that you don't have to pass it on every call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Truffle you can override the contract's defaults with [`.defaults()`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/v5.0.39/packages/contract/README.md#mycontractdefaultsnew_defaults)

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract.sol")

MyContract.defaults({
  from: "0x..."
})
```

[@truffle/contract documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-contract#mycontractdefaultsnew_defaults) (previously named truffle-contract)